# Outlook - insert text based on recipient

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to automatically insert text into an outgoing email depending on the recipient.  I found some code in an answer to another question (credit to 76Mel) that looks promising.  It seems that I could attach the code to ItemSend in ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
       For Each myRecipient In Item.Recipients
           If myRecipient.Address = "<EMAIL ADDRESS TO FIND>" Then 
           <code to add text>
           End If
       Next
   End If
End Sub
```

What would the code be that adds the text to the body of the email - and would this even work?  Would this code fire before the email is sent, or is it already too late?

I do need it to be automated (creating a button or running the macro manually isn't really an option; it's a memory thing: if I could remember to run the macro, I could just add the text manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have added the comments so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it :) If you still have a question, simply ask...

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    '~~> Check if it is an email
    If TypeName(Item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub

    Dim srchString As String, NewText As String
    
    '~~> Email Address which you want to search for
    srchString = "abc@gmail.com"
    
    '~~> New text that you want to add
    NewText = "Blah Blah"
    
    '~~> Search To, CC, BCC Fields
    If InStr(1, Item.To, srchString, vbTextCompare) Or _
    InStr(1, Item.CC, srchString, vbTextCompare) Or _
    InStr(1, Item.BCC, srchString, vbTextCompare) Then
        '~~> Add the relevant text to the body
        Item.Body = Item.Body & vbNewLine & NewText
    End If
End Sub
```

I would recommend this MSDN Link.

**Topic**: MailItem Object Members

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176688%28v=office.12%29.aspx

**Quote From the Above Link**

> Represents a mail message in an Inbox folder.
>
> Lists all Methods / Properties for a MailItem Object

Comment: This is good, but your code doesn't check if the outgoing item is an email.

Comment: Thank you - your code is clear.  That appears to be what I'm after - I copied the code into Itemsend & tested, but my text wasn't added.  I even removed the check for the email (so it would in theory, add the text to all emails) and it still didn't add the text.

Comment: @JP" Good Point. I will update it shortly. @Chip: I have tested the code and it worked. Can I see the exact code that you tried?

Comment: @Chip After pasting in the code, restart Outlook. Set a breakpoint in the code and then send out an email that would trigger the `If` statement.

Comment: I had failed to restart outlook - everything is working perfectly now.  It would be difficult to exaggerate how much you've helped me today - Thank you!.