# Add text to body of email based on recipient specified

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've been looking around and I can't find an answer to this question.

What I want to do is have text automatically added to the body of an email message when the "To:"(email recipient) field is a specific email address.

I've tried to find an event that fires while filling out a new email but haven't had much luck.

This question is similar, [Outlook - insert text based on recipient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264834/outlook-insert-text-based-on-recipient), but his solution only works when the message sends. I need it to happen before the message is sent so the user can continue to fill out the email.

For example, if I fill out "austin@company.com" in the "To:" field, the body of the email would get filled with pre-specified. In my case I want to have text added so the user knows what to fill out next, like a template.

An example of the template, to be added to the body of the message:

```
Time: 
Location: 
Username:
Comments:
```

And the user would fill out the email from there, after each item.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS Exchange, a Transport Rule will achieve this.  The only downside is it appends/replaces the text on the way out after send his hit so you wouldn't see the added text during message composition.  You can also define further filters so it only happens IF user A sends to user B to prevent the rule from firing for all outbound mail to user B.

There are a lot of options a Transport Rule can achieve over Outlook Rules.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600437(v=exchg.150).aspx

This link shows how legal disclaimers can be added (even with HTML markup) and would be a similar rule for outbound may based on your TO filter needs.

**Update**:

For MS Exchange &/OR Outlook, rules and automation are event driven.  Adding someone to the TO field isn't a client event so there's nothing to trigger the addition of a message body.  Outlook could process data if a 3rd party tool was written to trigger on TO field population.

And Transport rules only process messages going in and out of various message transports, i.e. inbound/outbound during message inspection.  So while it can be automated at several stages during message submission, at the client level, it would require manual input (copy/pasting of the additional body).  That's a limitation of most mail clients too, not just Outlook.

Other applications have this feature but they're generally more expensive service desk/support tools like Service-Now or Siebel Customer Center... and even then it's manually scripted one-off functionality.

Comment: No this is not what I need. I need the text added to the body of the message before it is sent out, so the user filling out the email can see it. I will update my question with another example.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It might not be possible then the way I want to do it. Excel-VBA has "worksheet_change" event that triggers every time anything is altered; I wish outlook had the same.

Comment: Yea, I've had that request several times for outlook to behave more like other office apps... that's why Mail merge is still a word function.  ;-)  If someone comes up with a better idea, I'll delete my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the MailItem.PropertyChange event and if the property name is To, CC or BCC, loop through the recipients looking for a match.